# NodeJS - Returning 'undefined'

Tags: node.js

I am learning NodeJS (generally I write in PHP). Please help me figure out the Promises. Now the 'getDataFromDir' function returns 'undefined'. I read the documentation, but apparently I don't fully understand something. Thanks in advance!

```
const host = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;
const __dirname = process.cwd();

async function getDataFromDir(fileName){
    fsp
        .readdir(path.join(fileName))
        .then(async (indir) => {
            const list = []
            for (const item of indir) {
                const src = await fsp.stat(path.join(fileName, item))
                list.push(item)
            }
            return list;
        })
}

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
    const result = await getDataFromDir(__dirname);
    result
        .then((list) => {
            console.log(list);
    });
});
```

Comment: `getDataFromDir` doesn't have a return statement. You need to make it `return fsp.readdir...`

Comment: Also the line `const result = await getDataFromDir(__dirname);` since you have `await` result is not a promise any more. You can simply use it `console.log(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your return statement is returning only for the callback function under your `.then` statement. You should be able to use the await statement with your initial request and achieve a similar result.

```js
async function getDataFromDir(fileName){
    let indir = await fsp.readdir(path.join(fileName));
    const list = [];
    for (const item of indir) {
        const src = await fsp.stat(path.join(fileName, item));
        list.push(item);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. Confused with promises, with your answer it became clearer)